# Unable to build Nativescript Android app signed APK

Tags: android, compilation, nativescript

I am trying to build a Nativescript app for the Android platform. I am running this command │

```
$ tns build android [--compileSdk API Level] [--key-store-path File Path --key-store-password Password│ -key-store-alias Name --key-store-alias-password Password] [--release--static-bindings--copy-to
```

File Path with all of the necessary components filled in. Each time I run it, it just gives me a message with the necessary steps to build it. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Same problem. I must tell I try --swith-name=value and --swith-name value. Both gives the same result, I tell tns print help about tns build android.

Answer (score 0):

first check if every thing is ok with this command `tns doctor` then :

1-`tns create projectname` will create a nativescript project,

2-In created project `tns platform add android` will add android to platforms folder and you can build for android,

3-In created project `tns build android` will just build it (automatically do `tns platforms add android` job if you didnt run that) but will not deploy to device,

4-In created project `tns run android` will build and deploy to device( automatically do `tns platforms add android` job if you didnt run that)